# Java big decimal or double

Tags: java, floating-point, type-conversion, bigdecimal

I have a number in the format of (13,2) 13 digits and 2 decimal places. I need to do some calculation on it (like multiplication, division). I am planning to use `BigDecimal` for the calculations. Shall i use double or float for the calculation as `BigDecimal` is bit on slower side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How using BigDecimal would affect application performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378044/how-using-bigdecimal-would-affect-application-performance)

Comment: What precision do you need for the calculations? And what are your performance requirements?

Comment: What precision do you need? When you divide, do you need only the whole number or also the fraction?

Comment: What is the data? If it's money, *never* use `double,` always `BigDecimal.` Or get the database to do the calculations for you, if there's a database. NB These are decimal *places,* not 'decimals', and it's 'multiplication', not 'multiple'.

Comment: how often do you use the number for calculation?! do you use the whole number or just decimals?!

Comment: @KennyTaiHuynh and others:  Can we **PLEASE** get out of this meaningless habit of using the word 'decimals' where 'decimal *places*' is meant? 'Decimal' is a radix, not a part of a number. I've also seen it used to mean 'decimal point', which shows how futile it all is.

Comment: Thanks EJP. will care this from now on.

Comment: Also, what is the size of the dataset? If you're doing BigDecimal calculations (vs. float) on 100 values the performance difference is meaningless, where 100 million values it might be a consideration (but always _behind_ correctness, as Daniel Pryden answers).

Comment: @EJP: [It can also mean decimal places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_%28disambiguation%29).

Answer (score 7):

The most important consideration is not speed but correctness.

If your value is a sample of a [*continuous* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_discrete_variables#Continuous_variables), like a measurement of a real-world property like size, distance, weight, angle, etc., then an [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) `double` or `float` is probably a better choice. This is because in this case powers of ten are not necessarily "rounder" than other values (e.g. angular measurements in radians can be transcendental numbers but still "round").

If your value is a [*discrete* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_discrete_variables#Discrete_variables) like a measurement of money, then **double is incorrect** and a floating-point decimal type like `BigDecimal` is correct. This is because, in this case, discrete increments are meaningful, and a value of "0.01" is "rounder" and more correct than a number like "0.009999999999999" or "0.010000000000000001".

Comment: Exactly. You can get the wrong answer in zero time, if time is your only consideration.

Comment: does your answer change for base 2 "round" values? like binary byte values, `Mib, TiB,..` etc. I'm guessing not, because the binary values are descrete.

Comment: @activedecay: People don't usually talk about base-2 in the context of values between 0 and 1, but if you mean negative powers of two, then that's exactly how IEEE 754 floating-point works. It will "round off" to 1/256, but not to 1/100.

Comment: Let me clarify, @Dan, if I convert values from GiB to TiB, there will sometimes be a fractional component. When I store the TiB number, should I use BigDecimal because the TiB values are descrete? Said another way, converting back from TiB to GiB shouldn't be lossy.

Comment: ah I think i get it now Dan. `1/(2^x)` will easily be represented by IEEE-754 floating point, as long as x is small.

Comment: @activedecay: Bytes are a discrete measurement, so I would just store an integer in bytes and then handle GiB, TiB etc in formatting. Modern CPUs can handle 128-bit integers, which will be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, most natural representation for data with two decimal places is `BigDecimal` with scale factor 2. Start with that. In most cases it will be fast enough.

If, when measured, it really is a serious performance problem, there are two more options:

1. Use `long` to represent the number of hundredths. For example, US currency can be represented exactly as a `long` number of cents. Be very careful to ensure variable names and comments make it clear where dollars are being used, and where cents are being used.
2. Use `double` to represent the amount as a fraction. This avoids the dollars-vs-cents bookkeeping, at the expense of rounding issues. You may need to periodically correct the rounding by multiplying by 100, rounding to nearest integer, and dividing by 100 again